# Can I symlink GitHub Actions to directories inside repo?

Tags: github-actions

I have a repo, and I have a code generator that generates GitHub Actions inside some directories.

For example:

```
- repo_root
  - .github/workflows
    - site.yml <= this is a relative symlink to site's build.yml
    - blog.yml <= this is a relative symlink to blog's build.yml
  - site
    - .github/workflows/build.yml
  - blog
    - .github/workflows/build.yml
```

I have created those symlinks, using this command and I can verify that they are correct (by `cat` or by `ls -lah`):

```
ln -s -f -r /repo/site/.github/workflows/build.yml /repo/.github/workflows/build.yml
```

However, they are not recognized in GitHub as Actions and they immediately fail.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Nope, I had to write a script to copy/paste my inner actions to the `.github/workflows` directory.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like symlinks are not processed by the GitHub Action pipeline. I have a similar need with git submodules and the pipeline immediately returns with a symlink path to the submodule's GitHub action yaml file.

[Screenshot of the failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf98T.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's a shame the GitHub does not support this.